# exculde content type from search result even for admin

Tags: search, users

Is it possible to disable specific content type from search result even from 
administrator, I did for all user types except the administrator using
[Search configuration](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_config) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you're attempting if you implement [Apache Solr](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr) which has all kinds of cool options - but that involves actually setting up Solr on your server which might be overkill if that is all you wish to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Search API for that. You can setup search API with database search to index only content type that you need.

- [Search API](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api)
- [Search API Database Search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_db)